# VB.NET check if specific process is running by specific username then kill it

Tags: vb.net, kill, runas

I try create app, that will be checking (using timer) if users trying run cmd.exe in Administrator privileges, if yes, then I want to kill it.
I don't know how to do it.
below is code that I'm using but... give me an error when no cmd's is runing.

PS: this application is running by standard user and run listed (allowed) app as Administrator (I don't want to run cmd in admin privilages). So I need to sent credentials to kill app (cmd) as admin that is started by admin.

```
        Dim username As String = "Administrator"
        Dim password As SecureString = ConvertToSecureString("xxPASSWRORDxx")
        Dim domain As String = Nothing
        Dim filename As String = ".\pskill.exe -u Administrator cmd.exe"
        Try
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, username, password, domain)
        Catch ex As Win32Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password.",
        "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: If the users can run cmd with administrative privileges, they already have full access to the computer, at which point you have already lost. [What are you trying to achieve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640)

Comment: they can run only listed app, but as you know, if somebody run app in admin privileges, some app have browse button for explorer.exe and then they can "open windows command here" from shift + right click.

Comment: This can be solved with group policies: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx - But if they have administrative privileges then there will always be a way around it.

Comment: Yes, but also I login as administrator to this station and run some cmd's commands. I don't want to have blocked apps for me to. I want for normal users run some listed apps/commands (change IP on some IP ports) etc. as administrator. All other apps started as admin should be killed